# Release of the source code for twitter app for android

Tags: android, twitter

Does any one know if or when twitter is going to release the source code for the android app?

The release was [announced back in April](http://blog.twitter.com/2010/04/twitter-for-android-robots-like-to.html)

> We had a great time working with the Android team and are thrilled that Google will be open sourcing the code used in this app in the near future. We look forward to the amazing experiences developers will create using Twitter APIs in their upcoming Android apps.

and it seems like they are not actually going to release it after all.

Comment: dunno I thought for sure it would just be in the git when they released the source for android 2.2    I've been itching to look at the source for a long time, I'm upset they took out the live background before doing so as well.

Comment: which live background did the took out?

Comment: the clouds and bird on the dashboard

Comment: maybee it was using a lot CPU ont the android phone? maybee it's not perferable

Comment: still would like to see how it was accomplished, it never seemed to hurt my phone, seems they just removed it to make room for more buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter has made no announcements about the source code for Twitter for Android. I have asked several times on the Google Group with no official response. The app has basically been rewritten and at this point I do not expect Twitter to release the source code.